# ¿Como puedo hacer para que se guarden las imágenes en otra carpeta PHP?

Tags: php, imagen

Es un codigo php, he conseguido que las imagenes se guarden en el servidor, pero quiero que se guarden en una carpeta en específico.

```
$directorioTemp = $_FILES ['imagen'] ['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($directorioTemp, $_FILES ['imagen'] ['name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iría algo como lo siguiente

```php
    try{
        $carpetaDestinoDocumento = "ARCHIVOS/DOCs/"; //debe existir
        $origenDocumento= $_FILES["documento"]["tmp_name"];
        move_uploaded_file($origenDocumento, $carpetaDestinoDocumento)
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage()
    }
```

Comment: no recomiendo usar @ para ocultar los errores en desarrollo ni en produccion ... una mejor un try catch y dependiendo del ambiente puedes controlar si lo muestras por pantalla o envias el error a un log y muestras al usuario la clave timesptamp por si lo reporta...

Comment: trabajas con algun framework en particular?

Comment: Recomendable colocar la ruta completa del destino, incluyendo el nombre final del archivo con su extensión `"$dirDestino/$nombreArchivo";`. Ver [ejemplo oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples).